# Get selected values from MultiCombo in Ext.NEt via JS

Tags: ext.net

I am using Ext.Net I have a form with a ComboBox which I have just changed to a MultiCombo.

Previously I used "SelectEnquiry.getValues()" to retrieve the selected item and pass it into a parameter used with a Button Direct Event.

How do I get the selected values when using the MultiCombo?

Combo Box Bit

```
    <ext:MultiCombo runat="server" ID="SelectEnquiry" FieldLabel="Enquiry" AnchorHorizontal="95%" Editable="false" ValueField="Id" DisplayField="ProviderName" TypeAhead="true" Mode="Local" ForceSelection="true" TriggerAction="All" EmptyText="Select Enquiry" ValueNotFoundText="Select Enquiry" ItemSelector="div.list-item" SelectOnFocus="true" AllowBlank="false">
```

Button form submit bit

```
 <ext:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonEmailTaskAccept" Text="OK">
        <Listeners>
            <Click Handler="if (PanelUnlinked.isVisible() && !$form.validate( [SelectProject, SelectEnquiry])) return false;">
            </Click>
        </Listeners>
        <DirectEvents>
            <Click Url='<%# Url.Action("CompleteEmailTask") %>' AutoDataBind="true"
            Success="window.$messageBus.publish('task-admin', 'inbox-changed');
            window.$messageBus.publish('task-admin', 'task-changed');
            WindowAssignEmail.close()" Failure="$shell.requestFailedHandler(response, null)"
                Json="true">
                <EventMask ShowMask="true"></EventMask>
                <ExtraParams>
                    <ext:Parameter Name="emailResponseId" Value="<%# Model.EmailResponse.Id %>" Mode="Value"
                        AutoDataBind="true" />
                    <ext:Parameter Name="enquiryId" Value="SelectEnquiry.getValues()" Mode="Raw" />
                    <ext:Parameter Name="documentList" Value="buildSelectionList()" Mode="Raw" />
                </ExtraParams>
            </Click>
        </DirectEvents>
    </ext:Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that it could not locate the control I was try to get the value from.

So managed to solve it by doing:

```
#{SelectEnquiry}.getSelectedValues()
```

Comment: Why was this marked down?  It is the solution to the problem.  Granted it's my solution but, how else do I indicate it solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

With `<ext:MultiCombo>` you can just call `.getValue()` to return an Array of selected values. I'll look into adding `.getValues()` as well, so it's consistent with the `<ext:ComboBox>` api.

**Edit**

It appears the `ComboBox` does not have a client-side `.getValues()` function, so we won't be adding to the `MultiCombo`. Just use `.getValue()`, which is standardised across all Form Fields.